# eigenfunctions of Dirichlet laplacian in perturbed domain of the disk

Tags: boundary-value-problem, laplacian, perturbation-theory, eigenfunctions

Let $\varepsilon$ a small positive real and $\Omega_\varepsilon$ an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $$\Omega_\varepsilon=\{(x,y) \mid x = R(\theta,\varepsilon) \cos(\theta)\quad y=R(\theta,\varepsilon) \sin(\theta)\}$$ where $R(\theta,\varepsilon)=1+\varepsilon f(\theta)$
such that $f$ is regular $2\pi$-periodic function.

Let $u_1^\varepsilon $ the first eigenfunction of Dirichlet problem

\begin{align}
-\Delta u = \lambda u & & & \text{ in } \Omega_\varepsilon \\[8pt]
\text{and } u=0 & & & \text{ in } \partial \Omega_\varepsilon
\end{align}

1-Can I write $u_1^\varepsilon =A_0 J_0(\sqrt{\lambda }r)+\varepsilon \sum\limits_{\substack{n\in \mathbb{Z} \\}} A_n J_n(\sqrt{\lambda} r) e^{(in\theta)}$ ?

2-if so why ?

PS : $J_n$ is the  bessel function of the first kind and $A_i \in \mathbb{C}$